# Why is the focus stuck on TextField once I add a listener to my TextEditingController to vary the textSize in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to change the text size in my text field according to the number of characters typed in. I have set an upper bound of 50 and lower bound of 25 and initialized the textsize according to the length of the initial value in the controller for the text field.

This is the code for adding the listener in `initState()`

```
    @override
    void initState(){
    super.initState();
    setState(() {
      _controller.text = widget.list.listHeader;
    });
    Timer.run(() {
      _initializeTextStyle();
    });
    _controller.addListener(_setHeader);
    _controller.addListener(_changeTextSize);
  }
```

and the following is the code for `_changeTextSize`

```
    TextStyle _changeTextSize(){
    var fieldWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.80 - 12.0;
    TextSpan ts = new TextSpan(style: textStyle, text: _controller.text);
    tp = new TextPainter(text: ts, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
    tp.layout();
    var textWidth = tp.width;
      if((textWidth - fieldWidth) > 5){
        print(textWidth.toString() + " " + fieldWidth.toString());
        setState(() {
          textStyle = TextStyle(
              color: Colors.brown,
              fontSize: max(textStyle.fontSize - 1, 25),
              fontFamily: 'DancingScript');
        });
      } else if((textWidth - fieldWidth) < -5){
        setState(() {
          textStyle = TextStyle(
              color: Colors.brown,
              fontSize: min(textStyle.fontSize + 1, 50),
              fontFamily: 'DancingScript');
        });
    }}
```

This is where I have created the widget

```
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      final listView = new Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
                padding: _padding * 2,
                child: TextField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      cursorColor: Colors.black38,
                      maxLength: 50,
                      autofocus: false,
                      maxLengthEnforced: true,
                      controller: _controller,
                      style: textStyle,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.brown,
                              fontSize: 30,
                              fontFamily: 'DancingScript'),
                          labelText: 'Title...'))),
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.40,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75,
              child: new ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: widget.list.listItems.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                    final item = widget.list.listItems[index];
                    return Dismissible(
                      key: UniqueKey(),
                      direction: DismissDirection.startToEnd,
                      child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.015),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              widget.list.listItems[index],
                              IconButton(
                                iconSize: _getIconSize(),
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.delete_forever,
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    widget.list.removeWithFlags(index);
                                  });
                                },
                              )
                            ],
                          )
                      ),
                      onDismissed: (direction) {
                        setState(() {
                          widget.list.removeWithFlags(index);
                        });
                      },
                    );
                  })
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.add,
                size: _getIconSize(),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  widget.list.addWithFlags(new Item.flag(focusFlag: true));
                });
              },
            )
          ]
        ));
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.80,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.70,
        child: listView,
      )
    );
  }
```

The problem that I am facing is that once I take focus to the first TextField(the one with the `_controller`), it gets stuck there and I am not able to shift focus to any other text field in the layout.

[Screenshot of the widget. The focus is stuck on the header part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSA91.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The focus was getting stuck on the textfield because `_changeTextSize` function calls `setState` everytime. This causes the app to keep building in a loop, thus it gets stuck.

On editing the code to call `setState` only when some condition is satisfied, the problem goes away.

Instead of trying to edit fontsize in this way, I went for a helpful third-party library for this purpose - [auto_size_text_field](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text_field)

```
    Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.60,
      child: AutoSizeTextField(
        cursorColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        controller: _controller,
        autofocus: widget.focusFlag,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black54,
          fontSize: 20,
        ),
      ),
    ),
```